# Understanding lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am reading through Eloquent JavaScript and have been stuck trying to understand lists for about two days so I figured I would finally ask a question. The example they give in the book is:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

Now I think I understand the example... There is a list object and it has properties value and rest. Then, rest has properties of value and rest, etc... However, I don't understand what rest is or even stands for. Does the rest property contain an object? So, list.rest.value would == 2? How is this useful? Some ways I could see this as useful are having a list Car, with prop engine, gauge, etc, with further properties of accelerate, brake, low fuel... How would something like this be achieved?

I do apologize for the "all overness" of this post, I don't exactly know what to ask or how to phrase it. It seems like the book only explained objects and properties, but never actually having objects as an objects property.

Thank you all in advance, and if you need any clarification or more info I will try to provide it.

Comment: 1s q:) can contain anything...

Comment: 2nd q:) So, list.rest.value would == 2? did you try? Obviously yes..

Comment: 3rd q:) depends on your requirement how you implement....

Comment: First of all... this variable is just named as `list`.. it is not a list. It is a JavaScript Object. So... In JavaScript objects have attributes... and an attribute can be anything String, List or an Object.

Comment: @sarveshseri to be fair to OP, Eloquent Javascript literally defines this data stucture as a "list." So it isn't something OP just made up. In fact, I arrived at this question via Google immediately after having read the same section that OP did with pretty much the same question as OP. So for that reason, this question is useful to me. (See: https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#list)

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of a linked list. Each node in the list has a reference to the next node. 'Rest' is an object (the next node in the list) that also contains every other node in the list (via it's rest property).

The first value in the list would be `list.value;`. The second value in the list would be `list.rest.value;`. The items in the list can be shown as:

`item1 = list;
item2 = list.rest;
item3 = item2.rest;`

This continues until `itemX.rest` is null.

These two functions could be used to manage the list and may help you understand how iterating through it would work:

```
function addToList(item)
{
    if(!list)
    {
        list = item;
        return;
    }

    var temp = list;
    while(temp.rest)
    {
        temp = temp.rest;
    }
    temp.rest = item;
}

function printList()
{
    var temp = list;
    while (temp)
    {
        print temp.value; //i'm not sure what the javascript print function is
        temp = temp.rest
    }
}
```

The add function would be called like this: `addToList({ value:10, rest:null });`

Answer (score 1):

This code simply uses JavaScript Object Notion to define an object named `list`.

```
// Would simply define an empty object.
var list = {};
```

Now you can add some properties to the object.

```
// Would define an object with a single property: `value`.
var list = {
    value: 1
};
```

Using nested object declarations, you can give the `list` object child objects as well:

```
var list = {
    value: 1,
    rest: {}
};
```

Now `list.rest` is an empty object. You can fill that out by adding some properties:

```
var list = {
    value: 1,
    rest: {
        value: 2
    }
};
```

And your nesting can continue ad-infinitum. The object in your original post, the following is possible:

```
console.log(list.value); // 1
console.log(list.rest.value); // 2
console.log(list.rest.rest.value); // 3
```

It's important to understand that this in no way creates a class or includes any additional methods with the object. It seems to be structured as a linked list but provides no functionality to add/remove/modify (except by directly modifying the original object).

Answer (score 0):

In the example above the `list` variable is an associative array. This is JavaScript's version of an "object". While the property `list.value` ends up being typed as an integer, the property `list.rest` is typed as a nested associative array. The properties themselves can be any valid type. Many jQuery plugins are coded where the properties themselves are actually delegate functions.

The object you have described above in the example does not seem to me to be terribly useful beyond being an example of how this kind of object can contain references to other objects. However, when you begin applying this in an "object oriented" concept (keep in mind that it is not truly object oriented), it becomes more useful. You can then create your own "namespace" with properties, functions and delegates that can be re-used time and again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your information. I don't know if there is a best answer selection on this site or not, but I really do appreciate the help Justin, Joel, and Evan. I think the main part I was confused about is just practical application for real applications. I have messed around a little bit and came up with this and have a much better basic understanding now:

```js
var car = {
    engine: {
        turn_on: "Turned engine on",
        turn_off: "Turned engine off",
        desc: {
            size: "V6",
            year: 2000
        }
    },
    
    fuel: {
        level: 55
    }
};

function CheckFuel(fuel){
    if(fuel > 50){
         console.log("In good shape");   
    }
    else{
         console.log("We should fuel up");   
    }
}

console.log(car.engine.turn_on);
console.log(car.engine.turn_off);
console.log(car.engine.desc.size);
console.log(car.engine.desc.year);
CheckFuel(car.fuel.level);
```

Now time to practice iterating through. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure that is really a list but it does showcase some object oriented ideas (a car has an engine and fuel). I added some examples on iterating through this list structure in my 'answer'.